# Laravel Inertia (React), POST without defining route?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, post, routes, inertiajs

I'm new to laravel and react, currently trying to build a small project by using these two framework.

So I have installed breeze and react package, trying to figure it out how register process go through step by step.

`/route/web.php` :

```php
Route::get('/register', function () {
    return Inertia::render('auth/Register');
})->name('register');
```

`/resource/js/Pages/Auth/Register.tsx` :
so basically there's a form, after user fill all the information, it can submit.

```
const submit: FormEventHandler = (e) => {
    post(route('register'));
};
```

`/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisteredUserController.php` :

```php
class RegisteredUserController extends Controller
{
    public function create(): Response
    {
        return Inertia::render('Auth/Register');
    }

    public function store(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $request->validate([
            'userid' => 'required|string|unique:users|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/',
            'username' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:'.User::class,
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'userid' => $request->userid,
            'username' => $request->username,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
            'avatar' => 'avatars/default-avatar.png',
        ]);

        event(new Registered($user));

        Auth::login($user);

        return Redirect::route('profile.show', ['userid' => $user->userid]); 
    }
}
```

So I know that `/register` will return `Register.tsx` render by Inertia. And after user submit the form, it will make a `POST /register`, however `POST /register` is not define in `web.php`, so how does it know that it need to go to `store()` in `RegisteredUserController.php` ?

I've tested it multiple times, it stores user's information into database without an issue, but I just don't understand how it works.

Comment: It should show up in `php artisan route:list`. Probably defined in some package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to look in all the PHP route files, including the `auth.php` routes. You will likely find this route there since the Breeze starter kit creates this for you. It will look something like,

```php
Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
    Route::get('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'create'])
                ->name('register');

    Route::post('register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'store']);

   // ....
```

According to the scant [Laravel Breeze Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/starter-kits):

> ... you may navigate to your application's `/login` or `/register` URLs in your web browser. All of Breeze's routes are defined within the `routes/auth.php` file.